# Handling multiple CompletableFuture in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have list of futures. Now I do not want to wait for any particular future but obtain the future that has be executed in the futures list. Can I do this using polling in Java. My future returns an object which I use to set in Map.